# Accessing Ruby files in Dropbox

Tags: ruby

I am very new to programming in anything.  I want to get started with Ruby.  I have a pc and laptop.  I don't want to limit myself to just the pc.  As long as Ruby is installed on both, of course, can I keep my project files in DropBox so I can work on them from either device?
Thanks for your help.
Don

Comment: Of course, ruby files aren't special in dropbox. I highly recommend using actual source control tools, though.

Comment: There is nothing preventing you from using dropbox. But its better to use some kind of source control. Have a look at https://github.com/ to start with.

Comment: As essential as source control is, it can have a learning curve. Moreover, its benefits might not be obvious to someone who has never programmed. OP might prefer to concentrate on learning the very basics of programming first and leave other concepts for later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**. Source code files can be kept in Dropbox just like any other file. You can use Dropbox to keep your files in sync between your two computers.

As you find yourself more comfortable with programming and make programs of greater complexity, you will probably want to use a version control system (VCS), such as Git. Among many other things, a VCS will keep your project files centralized in a repository. If the repository is in the cloud (e.g. on GitHub) you will be able to access it from all your computers.

Comment: abl--thank you for your help.  I really appreciate you taking the time to answer.  I am so new I had not heard of a VCS so in my naivete I suggested Drop box.  But I know now and will be looking into this.  Again, thanks for your help.  Don